# Visual Studio 2010 Builds to wrong directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

My project's Output Path is set to "bin\Debug\"

I'm building it through VS2010 and it builds to ..\..\build\bin\x86\Debug (and not to bin\Debug). I can't find any other settings in the .sln or .csproj that might affect this. Ideas?

Comment: What language? C#, VB, and C++ all handle things slightly differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we have a (plugin?) to MSBuild that looks for a Before.targets file in any parent directory and was overwriting the OutDir based on that.